# How to make Xdebug working with Visual Studio Code on MacOS

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug

Since the "brew upgrade" the debugging of PHP code from Visual Studio Code does not work - the performance of the script does not stop at the breakpoint.

I checked PHP info and XDEBUG is loaded:

[image]

My configuration ( content of /usr/local/etc/php/7.4/conf.d/ext-xdebug.ini ) has not been changed:

```
[xdebug]
    zend_extension=xdebug
    xdebug.mode=debug
    xdebug.client_port = 9003
    xdebug.discover_client_host = false
    xdebug.log=/Users/marekstrop/zdroje/logs/xdebug_log.log
    xdebug.log_level=10;
    xdebug.output_dir=/Users/marekstrop/zdroje/tmp
```

Log output, when I run a PHP script is:

```
[1363] Log opened at 2023-09-06 06:24:59.552564
[1363] [Config] DEBUG: Checking if trigger 'XDEBUG_TRIGGER' is enabled for mode 'debug'
[1363] [Config] INFO: Trigger value for 'XDEBUG_TRIGGER' not found, falling back to 'XDEBUG_SESSION'
[1363] [Config] INFO: Trigger value for 'XDEBUG_SESSION' not found, so not activating
[1363] [Config] DEBUG: Checking if trigger 'XDEBUG_TRIGGER' is enabled for mode 'debug'
[1363] [Config] INFO: Trigger value for 'XDEBUG_TRIGGER' not found, falling back to 'XDEBUG_SESSION'
[1363] [Config] INFO: Trigger value for 'XDEBUG_SESSION' not found, so not activating
[1363] Log closed at 2023-09-06 06:24:59.570291
```

xdebug_info output is:

[image]

Any idea, what can be wrong or how to check it in more details?

UPDATED:

It started to work with this configuration:

```
[xdebug]
    zend_extension=xdebug
    xdebug.mode=debug
    xdebug.client_port = 9003
    xdebug.discover_client_host = false
    xdebug.start_with_request=yes
    xdebug.log=/Users/marekstrop/zdroje/logs/xdebug_log.log
    xdebug.log_level=10;
    xdebug.output_dir=/Users/marekstrop/zdroje/tmp
```

Comment: 1) What are you trying to debug -- a CLI script or a web page? 2) Show the output of `xdebug_info()` captured in the same way as you are trying to debug. It will show the live config for that environment. You may be using different PHP version now that may be using different php.ini etc.

Comment: I am trying to debug a PHP script. I normaly started the debug session using "green arrow" with "Listen for Xdebug" configuration before the brew upgrade. It resulted any running PHP script to stop on any breakpoint created using VSC. Now it passes all of them. I edited my question - I added xdebug_info output.

Comment: Enable Xdebug log (point it to a FILE in writeable place) and try to debug (after webserver restarting / ensure that you see the log path value in the `xdebug_info()` output -- so it's applied). Then check the log. If Xdebug tries to connect to the debug client then it will have that logged there. Right now it's possible that Xdebug does not see "debug me" flag... P.S. you can force Xdebug to try to debug every single request with `xdebug.start_with_request = yes` (your screenshot is too short and does not show all the params)

Comment: It works now. Thanks for the help. I updated the question with working configuration. Please, put your advice as answer and I'll mark it as the correct one.